# How to make a mute, unmute, tempmute command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

guys i am working on a discord bot i have ban,kick,nuke,ping commands but i need a mute , unmute, tempmute command but idk how to make all yt tutorial is so confusing and dont work please help me in making it
I am using discord.js v12
the prefix is $
i want the command to be $mute @user

this is my whole code since

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const express = require("express")

const app = express()


app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
  console.log("helloe")
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Ready")
})
const disbut = require('discord-buttons');
disbut(client);



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Beast Bot is ready');
    client.user.setActivity('Discord Ping Messages || $help || (Made by CaptainBeast#1394)  ', { type:"WATCHING"}).catch(console.error)
    
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
      console.log(`${guild.name} | ${guild.id}`);
    })
});




const ownerId = "602113193489203232";
const owner2Id = "725629309854679092";

client.on('clickButton', async(button) => {
  
  })

client.on("message", async message => {
    
    
    
    
    
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(ownerId)) {
       
        message.reply(`Thanks for pinging my owner you will be banned with in 24 hours :))`);
    
    
    };
    if (message.mentions.has(owner2Id)) {
       
      message.reply(`Thanks for pinging my co-owner you will be banned with in 24 hours :))`);

  };

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'nuke'){
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      message.channel.send('missing permissions')
  }

  message.channel.clone().then(channel => {
      channel.setPosition(message.channel.position)
      channel.send('nuked')
  })
  message.channel.delete()
  }




    if(message.content.startsWith("$download")){
    let button = new disbut.MessageButton()
  .setLabel("Download")
  .setURL('http://www.beaststudios.ga')
  .setStyle('url');

message.channel.send("Download Firebones at www.beaststudios.ga", button);
        
        
    }
    
    
  if(message.content.startsWith("~mute")) {
    if(message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
    {
      message.reply(`Thanks for pinging my co-owner you will be banned with in 24 hours :))`);

    }
  };


  if (!message.guild) return;

  // if the message content starts with "!ban"
  if (message.content.startsWith('$ban')) {

    if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
     // Assuming we mention someone in the message, this will return the user
    // Read more about mentions over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageMentions
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // If we have a user mentioned
    if (user) {
      // Now we get the member from the user
      const member = message.guild.members.resolve(user);
      // If the member is in the guild
      if (member) {
        /**
         * Ban the member
         * Make sure you run this on a member, not a user!
         * There are big differences between a user and a member
         * Read more about what ban options there are over at
         * https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban
         */
        member
          .ban({
            reason: 'They were bad!',
          })
          .then(() => {
            // We let the message author know we were able to ban the person
            message.channel.send(`Successfully banned ${user.tag} `);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // An error happened
            // This is generally due to the bot not being able to ban the member,
            // either due to missing permissions or role hierarchy
            message.channel.send('I was unable to ban the member');
            // Log the error
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        // The mentioned user isn't in this guild
        message.channel.send("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
    } else {
      // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
      message.channel.send("You didn't mention the user to ban!");
    }
    } else {
      message.channel.send('You dont have permission to ban ')
    }
    
  }




  if (message.content.startsWith('$kick')) {

    if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
     // Assuming we mention someone in the message, this will return the user
    // Read more about mentions over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageMentions
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // If we have a user mentioned
    if (user) {
      // Now we get the member from the user
      const member = message.guild.members.resolve(user);
      // If the member is in the guild
      if (member) {
        /**
         * Ban the member
         * Make sure you run this on a member, not a user!
         * There are big differences between a user and a member
         * Read more about what ban options there are over at
         * https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban
         */
        member
          .kick({
            reason: 'They were bad!',
          })
          .then(() => {
            // We let the message author know we were able to ban the person
            message.channel.send(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // An error happened
            // This is generally due to the bot not being able to ban the member,
            // either due to missing permissions or role hierarchy
            message.channel.send('I was unable to kick the member');
            // Log the error
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        // The mentioned user isn't in this guild
        message.channel.send("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
    } else {
      // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
      message.channel.send("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    }
    } else {
      message.channel.send('You dont have permission to kick')
    }
    
  }








});


// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const help = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Commands')
    .setURL('')
    .setAuthor('CaptainBeast', 'https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/307-3072086_discord-icon-discord-icon-png.png')
    .setDescription('Here are the list of some available commands')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/307-3072086_discord-icon-discord-icon-png.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Commands', value: ':) commands' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: '$help', value: 'Displays list of available commands', inline: true },
        { name: '$ping', value: 'sent pong ', inline: true },
    { name: '$download', value: 'sent link to download firebones ', inline: true },
    { name: '$ban @user', value: 'Bans a member  ', inline: true },
    { name: '$kick @user', value: 'Kicks a member  ', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('More stuffs coming soon', 'the bot is still under development', true)
    .setImage('')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Made by CaptainBeast#1394', 'https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/307-3072086_discord-icon-discord-icon-png.png');
    
    

  
    
  

const prefix = "$";
client.on("message", (message) => {
  // Exit and stop if it's not there
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "help")) {
    message.channel.send(help);
    
  } else
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "foo")) {
    message.channel.send("bar!");
  }
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
    message.channel.send("pong!");
  }
});

client.login('censored')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make a mute command is to remove talking permissions from "@everyone", and add the permissions to talk to your "member" rank.
So when the mute command is triggered the member rank will be removed, and a placeholder muted rank without extra permissions will be placed.
For further information on adding and removing roles check the documentation!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.